# Spring Boot cannot read from Oracle database after application restart

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle, spring-boot

My spring boot application cannot read from an Oracle DB instance.

If I configure the application to automatically create the schema and populate the DB via a `data.sql` file, then it works perfectly, like so:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always

...

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

But then if I then change the configuration to:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: never

...

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

and then restart the spring boot application, it can no longer read from the DB, even though all the tables and data that it created before the restart is still there in the DB.

*Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Or would you know where I could even start to try debugging it?*

This is the Oracle version:

`Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

This is the driver I'm using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the version of JPA:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and it's spring boot version 2.3.3

**UPDATE:**

The appears to happen after I write to the DB via Spring Boot, i.e. insert a new record, and then restart the application.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you please copy the stack trace?

Comment: There is no error or stack trace - there are simply zero records returned from every query after an application restart

Comment: Can you show your config that It worked `If I configure the application to automatically create the schema and populate the DB` ?

Comment: Sure thing - I've updated the question with the before and after configs